# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. Not able to add string foreign key

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am trying to create string foreign key constraint. Nut nothing is working.
Accounts table-

```
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('customer_id');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('customer_id')->on('customers');
        $table->string('ac_type_id');
        $table->string('ac_number')->primary();
        $table->string('ac_balance');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Customers table-

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('customer_id')->primary();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('mobile_no');
        $table->string('email_id');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->date('dob');[enter image description here][1]
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is error I'm getting always
[image: This is error I'm getting always]

Comment: Is Customer table created before the Accounts table? If not the Accounts table cant reference ```customer_id```. This is what is normally the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, Customer table is created before accounts table @geertjanknapen

Comment: Have you tried defining a specific length for the string `$table->string('customer_id',40)` in both tables